# Do ethereum-like chains share a JSON-RPC API?

Tags: json-rpc

For example, Polygon seems to have a *similar* JSON-RPC API, but I can't easily see whether it's actually the same API as the Ethereum spec.

Does anyone know whether the API specified [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/) only applies to Ethereum chain, or verbatim can be expected to be supported by other EVM chains?

In other words, is the API more accurately described as the "Ethereum JSON-RPC" or "EVM JSON-RPC"?